# Heroku Precompiling Rails 4 failing due to node?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, heroku

after running precompile (after pushing to heroku), i see a million ^^^^^^^^^^^^, and then:

```
   node.js:134
   throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
   ^
   SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
   at Module._compile (module.js:399:25)
   at Object..js (module.js:410:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:336:31)
   at Function._load (module.js:297:12)
   at Array.<anonymous> (module.js:423:10)
   at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:126:26)
```

and then after the trace:

```
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

I have this in my config/application.rb

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

and these 3 gems (outside of default ones, postgres one, and ones in test or dev)

```
gem 'devise'
gem 'angularjs-rails'
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

I have played around with a few things to get this to work. I have configured heroku to ignore test and dev gems.

Some of my angular files look like: 'source.controller.js', but i doubt that that is the issue.

Any help or clues would be great, and if any other info would be helpful, ill post it right away. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

precompiled on my own computer, added
config.assets.compress = false
to config

to devise;
config.secret_key = 'some1234keyq23' if Rails.env == 'production'

and now i got it working! hurray!